# How do I sent list of values as parameter to the inline SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

We have C# program to produce regular reports on yearly, monthly etc., basis.
This is the sample of inline SQL for a report.

```
SELECT DOB, MEMBNO FROM BASIC WHERE DOJ = @ReportRunDate AND STATUS IN @StatusList
```

Using SqlParameter we can send ReportRunDate as parmeter, But when comes @StatusList we can't find a proper way to pass this as parameter.

For eg @statusList whose values come from the input would looks like this 'AB',12','Z1'

We could achieve using string concatenation like below

```
string statusList = "'AB',12','Z1";
string sqlCmdText = SELECT DOB, MEMBNO FROM BASIC WHERE DOJ = @ReportRunDate AND STATUS IN (" + statusList + ")";
```

But we prefer to use all input values to the SQL as parameters.

**NOTE:**
 - The query I have mentioned is an example, the original query is of a page length and has more than one IN clauses. Also as per the spec, we are restricted to use Inline Query only.

Please give your guidance on

1. How do I parameterise StatusList variable?
2. There are dozens of reports which requires to use inline SQL, We are thinking of separating each sql from the C# code and moving them to embedded resource. Is this a best practice?

Thanks all.

Comment: You can not parameterize the list that goes to the `IN` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. below query should work..

`select * from  YourTableName where ','+@YourVariableName+',' like '%,'+YourColumnName+',%'`

Below is the script to test above query

```
CREATE TABLE #TT(test varchar(100))
insert into #TT values('abkk'),('cdll'),('ab'),('cd')

select * from #TT

declare @input varchar(100)
set @input = 'abkk,cdll'

select * from  #tt where ','+@input+',' like '%,'+test+',%'
```

Please mark this post as answer if it helps you!